# Finding a PEiD database

Tags: database, malware, malware-detection

Where can I get the latest version of the PEiD database? I know that one version is available in github (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guelfoweb/peframe/5beta/peframe/signatures/userdb.txt), but it is more than one year old and it has approximately 4000 signatures.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the database to use in yara, There's a yara-rules github page [here](https://github.com/Yara-Rules/rules) that has a lot of preexisting rules and seems to be quite up to date. hope this helps!